# Scaling to 1:1 in QGIS Cloud

Tags: scale, qgis-cloud

Someone knows if with QGIS cloud Pro Plan, it's possible have a scale till 1:1. I use QGIS to draw small stuff on my gis (archaeological finds, as really small pottery's sherds) and I need a scale smaller than 1:624 as now I can view with QGIS cloud free plan.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you ask them, no. They will set the minimum scale, and any sensible provider will set this at way more than 1:1, because otherwise the storage and bandwidth costs could be astronomical, at least for tiled raster data.

I suggest you will either have to use GIS on the desktop, or create your own customised web service.

The bigger question is, of course, would the world implode if it were ever mapped at a 1:1 scale :)